# Pundit AuthorizationNotPerformedError/PolicyScopingNotPerformedError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, pundit

I'm new with the Pundit gem and I'm stuck on something.

I try to show a list with multiple records but I always get the error AuthorizationNotPreformedError.

What do I do wrong?

Controller:

```
def planning
  @plans = Order.all
  authorize @plans
end
```

Policy:

```
def planning?
  user.present?
end
```

Planning.html.haml

```
%h1 test
```

When I add this: `after_action :verify_policy_scoped, :only => planning, if: verify_policy_scoped?`

I get the PolicyScopingNotPerformedError.

Answer (score 1):

From [the README](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#ensuring-policies-and-scopes-are-used):

> Pundit tracks whether you have called `authorize` anywhere in your controller action. Pundit also adds a method to your controllers called `verify_authorized`
>
> ...
>
> Pundit also adds `verify_policy_scoped` to your controller. This will raise an exception similar to `verify_authorized`. However, it tracks if `policy_scope` is used instead of `authorize`.

You have mixed the two methods up. You've called `authorize`, but are checking whether `policy_scope` was called.

`policy_scope` is typically used for **collections** of record (such as your example, or more typically `index` actions), whereas `authorize` is typically used for **individual** records (such as `show`/`edit`/`update`/`destroy` actions).

In your case, however, what you've got currently doesn't necessarily warrant a policy at all - all you're checking is whether the user is signed in!

If you require a user to be signed in, but they are not, then your application should respond with a `401` error, not `403`. You may do this with, for example, `before_action :authorize` in your controller. (It depends how you have implemented authorization -- see the documentation on whatever library you're using, e.g. `devise`).